# Page Break / HTML Formatting Issues in Outlook 2007/2010

Tags: outlook, html-rendering

We have a very lengthy newsletter that has been designed and developed to look great in Email Clients.  It's very simple, and we really tried adhering to the limitations of viewing HTML in Email Clients, including Outlook 2007/2010.  And yes, I'm fully aware that Outlook 2007/2010 uses the Word HTML Formatting Engine, which is pretty gimped.

However, we have a long newsletter, that works perfectly in every email client and web browser on the planet, except for Outlook 2007/2010.  Here is an image of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QUvt.gif

Notice the weird line.  You can highlight this line and copy and paste the text here just fine, and when you look at the source, the text is obviously there.  This occurs multiple times throughout newsletter.  It seems to repeat about every "page" that the Word HTML Rendering Engine would likely want to put a page break on.  When you add or subtract content from this page, the weird line remains, but just in different spots of the text.

So my question is...

Is this really an Outlook 2007/2010 bug, and is there any way to overcome it on our side?  We've already considered the option of reducing the size of the newsletter (it's well over 10 pages printed out), but our client that this is for won't let that fly.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing markup, but here's what they support. Make sure you aren't using anything overly creative?
[Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the link above was only useful in directing us towards really inspecting the CSS carefully.  Short of that it was difficult to really tell what was going on.  Having said that, it was a "MARGIN: 10px" style on the BODY tag, that was causing the strange breaks.  Kind of weird, but removing that solved the issue.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me
`<p style="page-break-before: always">&nbsp;</p>`